# powershell invoke rest api toward AWX

Tags: powershell, rest, ansible-awx

I'm struggling for last week or more with sending rest api command from powershell to add host in AWX(from curl is working). When I sent one parameter is worki but I need to send also variables

```
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic $VfAwxTokenX")
$Headers.Add('Content-Type', 'application/json')
$body = @{
  name = '$vmname'
  variables = 'test'

}| ConvertTo-Json  
write-output    $body
$response = Invoke-RestMethod 'https://awx/api/v2/inventories/2/hosts/' -Method 'POST' -Headers $headers -UseBasicParsing -Body $body
```

and error what i get:

> {
> "name":  "wewewe",
> "variables":  "test" } Invoke-RestMethod : {"variables":["Cannot parse as JSON (error: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)) or
> YAML  (error: Input type `str` is not a dictionary)."]} At line:32
> char:13
>
> - $response = Invoke-RestMethod 'https://awx/api ...
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> - CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod],
>   WebException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

Maybe any one of users had that issue and now how to overcome it?

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, the parameter `variables` should be defined as  JSON or YAML format. For more details, please refer to [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/towerapi/api_ref.html#/Inventories/Inventories_inventories_hosts_create).
[image]

For more details about how to call the API, please refer to the [blog](https://medium.com/@claudio.domingos/ansible-awx-from-scratch-to-rest-api-part-3-of-8-3adcf539031f).

Answer (score 0):

the problem was prosaic

```
  variables = 'test'
```

if i put anything else then test is working :/